# change navigator date format in highstock

Tags: highcharts, navigator

I wanted to change the navigator date format for example from Jul'12 to 2012.

How should I do it?

[image: navigator]

Please help...

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use xAxis parameter for navigator and define labels option (as in standard axis).

http://jsfiddle.net/XGunG/

```
navigator: {
        xAxis: {
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%Y',
                week: '%Y',
                month: '%Y',
                year: '%Y'
            }
        }
    },
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.xAxis
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats